# How to properly close a form?

Tags: c#, forms

I close a form in `C#`:

```
loginForm.Close();
```

However, after that I can open it anymore, the following doesn't work:

```
loginForm.ShowDialog();
```

Why is that?

Comment: close meaning the form is disposed. To get it make you have to recreate. Try hiding it rather than closing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most likely the underlying handles are disposed not to mention anything that ran in the constructor won't run again.  Plus dialogs are a special beast and may have internal flags to indicate modal completion.

It's generally a bad idea to hang onto a window after it has been closed.  Perhaps *hiding and showing* the window is more to your liking?

Comment: just tried it, was very quick. However when closed with the X button, it won't show again?

Comment: Clicking the "X" button closes the form.

Comment: @recursive So what can I do then? I can't prevent user to do that

Comment: @Cher As recursive said, "X" closes a form not _hides_ it if that was your intent.  That's arguably a _new question_ but I will say why don't you override the `OnClosing` event?  If you do that you _can_ prevent a user from closing the form though it does pose new problems

Comment: @Cher You are quite welcome good sir/madam. Don't forget to vote as accordingly as it helps me feed my cat :)